# InsertAfter in jQuery giving error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null'; Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically, I created a modal and the button click will display the findings of the function in the modal. I'd like the button click to remove everything in that initial modal, and just display the findings.

Like I said I am getting `InsertAfter in jQuery giving error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null';`

I am perplexed because I am getting a handle of the modal container with:

```
modal = $('.modal')
```

And I am creating a output element like so:

```
 output = doc.createElement('p');

 output.setAttribute('id', 'output');
```

Which is going to be appended to the modal...

```
 $('#output').insertAfter(modal);
```

So why would I get an error of null, if I just created the container?

```
 doc.getElementById('output').innerHTML = out.join("\n");
```

HTML:

```
<script id="templateID" type="text/html">
    <div id="overlay">
        <div id="container" class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="twelve columns">
                    <div class="modal">
                        <p>This app will go through some of your markup to determmine if it could be more accessible.  We will start by checking the alt tags on your images, seeing if they exist, or if the tags are empty! <br> Lets get started!<br>
                        <a id="getStartedBtn" class="button button-primary modal-button">click-me</a>
                        </p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

JS:

```
function altChecker() {
        var doc = document,
            out = [],
            getStartedBtn = doc.getElementById('getStartedBtn'),
            modal = $('.modal'),
            output = doc.createElement('p');

            output.setAttribute('id', 'output');


        EventUtility.addHandler(getStartedBtn, 'click', function() {
            var all = doc.getElementsByTagName("IMG");

            for (var i = 0, max = all.length; i < max; i++) {
                var id = all[i].id;
                if (all[i].hasAttribute('alt')) {
                    out.push('Your image element, with the id of <strong>' + id + '</strong>, has an <strong> alt </strong> tag.');
                    var value = all[i].getAttribute('alt');
                    if (value != "") {
                        out.push(id + ' alt="' + value + '"');
                    } else {
                        out.push('But <strong>' + id + '\'s alt </strong> is empty');
                    }
                } else {
                    out.push(id + ' does not have alt');
                }
            }


            $('#output').insertAfter(modal);
            doc.getElementById('output').innerHTML = out.join("\n");



        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So why would I get an error of null, if I just created the container?

Because you haven't put it in the DOM, so `$("#output")` won't find it, even though it has an `id`; so the `$("#output").insertAfter(modal);` line is a no-op. Later, when you do `doc.getElementById('output')`, it's not in the DOM, so you get back `null`, and it fails.

Instead, since you already have a reference to the element in `output`, you'd do:

```
$(output).insertAfter(modal);
```

and later where you're using `getElementById`, there's no need to look it up again, you already have it, so:

```
output.innerHTML = out.join("\n");
```

or

```
$(output).html(out.join("\n"));
```

Comment: Thanks! But I just realized `insertAfter` does what it says (d'oh), inserts right after the element given. Is there a insertInto? Like it would it would insert into the `modal` div, thus whipping out the initial content?

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz: *"Is there a insertInto"* `appendTo` and `prependTo` both do that (at the end, and at the beginning, respectively). It's well worth spending just an hour or so reading through the jQuery API beginning to end. It really only takes that long, and it pays you back that time immediately. :-)

Comment: @Thanks T.J. — I should know better, as I use a great app which is like a pocket docset https://kapeli.com/dash